# appending regex matches to a dictionary

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a file in which there is the following info:

```
dogs_3351.txt:34.13559322033898
cats_1875.txt:23.25581395348837
cats_2231.txt:22.087912087912088
elephants_3535.txt:37.092592592592595
fish_1407.txt:24.132530120481928
fish_2078.txt:23.470588235294116
fish_2041.txt:23.564705882352943
fish_666.txt:23.17241379310345
fish_840.txt:21.77173913043478
```

I'm looking for a way to match the colon and append whatever appears afterwards (the numbers) to a dictionary the keys of which are the name of the animals in the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, regular expressions are unnecessary, provided that your data is well formatted and contains no surprises.

Assuming that `data` is a variable containing the string that you listed above:

```
dict(item.split(":") for item in data.split())
```

Comment: This is concise, but if I read the question correctly, doesn't do what they want.

Comment: @thg435: I suppose you're right. It should be a trivial matter to do one more `split()` to extract the animal name however.

Comment: notice this would only keep the last number for every animal instead of a list of all the values

Comment: @F.C.:Actually the keys appear to be unique. It all depends on whether OP wants to truncate the `txt` extension or everything after the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

```
t = """
dogs_3351.txt:34.13559322033898
cats_1875.txt:23.25581395348837
cats_2231.txt:22.087912087912088
elephants_3535.txt:37.092592592592595
fish_1407.txt:24.132530120481928
fish_2078.txt:23.470588235294116
fish_2041.txt:23.564705882352943
fish_666.txt:23.17241379310345
fish_840.txt:21.77173913043478
"""

import re

d = {}
for p, q in re.findall(r'^(.+?)_.+?:(.+)', t, re.M):
    d.setdefault(p, []).append(q)

print d
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use the python `find` method to locate the index of the colons which you can use to slice the string.

```
>>> x='dogs_3351.txt:34.13559322033898'
>>> key_index = x.find(':')
>>> key = x[:key_index]
>>> key
'dogs_3351.txt'
>>> value = x[key_index+1:]
>>> value
'34.13559322033898'
>>>
```

Read in each line of the file as a text and process the lines individually as above.

Answer (score 1):

Without regex and using [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = """dogs_3351.txt:34.13559322033898
cats_1875.txt:23.25581395348837
cats_2231.txt:22.087912087912088
elephants_3535.txt:37.092592592592595
fish_1407.txt:24.132530120481928
fish_2078.txt:23.470588235294116
fish_2041.txt:23.564705882352943
fish_666.txt:23.17241379310345
fish_840.txt:21.77173913043478"""

dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for l in data.splitlines():
    animal = l.split('_')[0]
    number = l.split(':')[-1]
    dictionary[animal] = dictionary[animal] + [number]
```

Just make sure your data is well formatted

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to defaultdict!